# @SpringBootApplication is not recognized with IntelliJ 2020.2

Tags: spring-boot

I created a Spring Boot project using Spring Initializer in IntelliJ 2020.2

While creating I chose Spring Boot 3.1.3, java 1.8.
In the folder "\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-parent",
there are versions such as:

- 2.3.3.RELEASE
- 2.3.4.RELEASE
- 2.4.1.

After the project was created, I changed the version of spring-boot-starter-parent from 3.1.3 to 2.4.1 and there was no error in the POM file.

However, in the application(.java) file, the @SpringBootApplication annotation is not recognized so I cannot build.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebuploadApplication {
```

Why is the @SpringBootApplication annotation not recognized?

Please help!

Comment: Its just a guess but something similar happened to me. I marked the java folder(src/main/java) as root folder. Right click on the folder and hover over 'Mark Directory as' and click 'Sources Root'. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.
I have solved the problem of not recognizing the @SpringBootApplication annotation.